# Entity Framework 6 not recognizing One-To-Many relationship when retrieving data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I insert my objects, they recognize they are one-to-many and the foreign key is correctly placed in the many side table.
When I retrieve my objects, they do not recognize the one-to-many on the one side table so I cannot access the ICollection of the many side objects. Specifically a Null Reference Exception is thrown when trying to access the collection/

In the explanation below, Incident is the one side and Disturbance is the many side. An Incident is associated with many Disturbances, but a Disturbance is a part of only one Incident.

*Disclaimer: due to some project constraints and some modules being built on top of other modules we are using Entity Framework in our DAL and have models cross cutting Business/Data. This may factor into the issue. I'm aware this isn't ideal, but this is where we are at and I haven't seen anything that explicitly says you cannot use EF like this.*

I have an Incident defined like this:

```
public class Incident
{
    public Incident()
    {

    }

    public Incident(List<Disturbance> sortedDisturbances)
    {
        StartTime = sortedDisturbances[0].StartTime;
        Disturbances = new List<Disturbance>(sortedDisturbances);
    }

    [Key]
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Disturbance> Disturbances { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="datetime2")]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

I had to add a parameterless constructor to deal with errors resulting from Entity Framework trying to use a parameterless constructor in certain areas.

I have a Disturbance defined like this :

```
public class Disturbance : IComparable<Disturbance>
{
    [Key]
    public int DisturbanceID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Disturbance other)
    {
        if (this.StartTime < other.StartTime)
            return 1;
        if (this.StartTime > other.StartTime)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I haven't read anything that said implementing an interface would break anything in Entity Framework so I did it.

This is how I add an Incident:

Business Layer:

```
private void MakeIncident(List<Disturbance> DisturbancesToAggregate)
{
    Incident incidentToInsert = new Incident(DisturbancesToAggregate);
    _iDAL.InsertIncident(incidentToInsert);
}
```

Data Layer:

```
public void InsertIncident(Incident incidentToInsert)
{
    using (var context = new InternalContext())
    {
        context.Incident.Add(incidentToInsert);                                                         
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I access my Incidents:

```
public IEnumerable<DomainModel.Disturbance> GetProcessedDisturbances()
{
    List<DomainModel.Disturbance> processedDisturbances = new List<DomainModel.Disturbance>();
    using(var context = new InternalContext())
    {
        foreach(var i in context.Incident)
        {
            foreach(var d in i.Disturbances)
            {
                processedDisturbances.Add(d);
            }
        }
    }
    return processedDisturbances;
}
```

The i.Disturbances Collection causes a Null Reference Exception. Is there something I need to call to force the context to get the Disturbances? Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

My ideas (I don't like any of them and don't want to do any of them):
1. Explicitly put the IncidentID on the Disturbance table (not even sure if this would work)
2. Force a lookup table by adding an ICollection of Incidents to Disturbances (its not a many-to-many relationship and I think this would prevent me from being able to clear all Disturbances from an Incident)
3. Explicitly define the relationship when the model is created. (I don't like the idea of having to do this, plus I think EF is half way there because it is inserting correctly.

Comment: Remember to always initialize your navigation properties inside your parameter-less constructor: `Disturbances = new List<Disturbance>();`

Comment: you have to refer the foriegn key check this link like this http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Check if lazy loading is turned on. Or try `var i in context.Incident.Include(e => e.Disturbances)`

Comment: I thought the virtual keyword forced lazy loading? Going to try the Include. If it works you should make it an answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev The only Include() I'm getting on the DbSet<Incident> takes a string as a parameter. Not seeing anything that takes a lambda expression.

Comment: @IvanStoev new Include(string) extension seems to only need string representing table name. Trying that.

Comment: You need to add an include statement for System.Data.Entity for the strongly typed version of Include.

Comment: What's your EF version? You can try of course `Include("Disturbances")`, but I prefer the lambda oveloads. And @RicardoPeres is right, you need to include `using` statement because the `Include` I'm referring to is defined inside the `System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions` class as an extension method.

Comment: @IvanStoev one thing that bothers me. Even if it is lazy loading, when I go to access i.Disturbances and it sees its null, isn't that when lazy loading is supposed to happen? Rather than throw a null reference exception?

Comment: @SmashCode Correct. That's why my first comment was to check if the lazy loading is **on**. `virtual` keyword is just one of the things. Check if your `DbContext` `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` and `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` properties are `true`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok, thanks, that helps clear it all up. You should put all of this into an answer.

Comment: @SmashCode No worry mate, glad that helped. All that info is available in the link posted by the answerer, please feel free to accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because of lazy loading in EF. We need to Eagerly loading the data. To know more about them, please refer the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I think this is in the right direction, however the only .Include() available takes a string as a parameter, not a lambda expression. Currently looking for more information on the Include extension.

Comment: Try using using System.Data.Entity namespace as that method is defined there only.